# Plot the participation on changes in a code by individuals in R

Tags: r

I got a dataframe for a project where there are for example two workers which take place in this project.
Every change ist documentated and the frame looks like this:

```
      devf    lines_add  lines_del
[1,] "egamma" "660"      "527"
[2,] "egamma" "8"        "2"  
[3,] "egamma" "14"       "3"  
[4,] "egamma" "128"      "8"  
[5,] "egamma" "67"       "5"  
[6,] "egamma" "74"       "248"
[7,] "egamma" "20"       "6"  
[8,] "egamma" "9"        "7"  
[9,] "egamma" "148"      "10" 
[10,] "egamma" "0"        "0"  
[11,] "egamma" "0"        "0"  
[12,] "egamma" "2"        "0"  
[13,] "egamma" "3"        "3"  
[14,] "egamma" "1"        "1"  
[15,] "egamma" "4"        "3"  
[16,] "emeade" "1"        "0"  
[17,] "emeade" "2"        "0"  
[18,] "emeade" "15"       "22" 
[19,] "emeade" "20"       "4"  
[20,] "egamma" "1"        "1"
```

I started to write a function but i dont get an idea for how to calculate the value on the y-axe.
Here is the function so far:

```
myplot.participation<- function(x){
  count.dev<- length(levels(x$devf))
  t= seq(0, count.dev, 0.5)
  z= tapply(t, )
  plot(t,z, type="l", col="green", lwd=5, xlab="Individuals", ylab="Participation")
  title("developer participation")  
 }
```

Any help for how to resolve this is welcome.
Here an example how the Plot should look like. The
solid line in the Figure shows the cumulative proportion of changes against the number of
contributors.
[image]

Comment: What does the change mean? What is the role of lines_add?

Comment: lines added means the dev has addes x lines in a code. I want to get the cumulative proportion of code changes in this project. For example here the dotline is ment for the lines added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
newdf <- aggregate(df[2:3], by= list(df$devf), FUN = "sum")

newdf<- rbind(c(NA,0,0), newdf)
names(newdf) <- c("Participant", "lines_add", "lines_del")
newdf$lines_add <- cumsum(newdf$lines_add)/sum(newdf$lines_add)
newdf$lines_del <- cumsum(newdf$lines_del)/sum(newdf$lines_del)
newdf$Participant <- seq(0, length(newdf$Participant)-1)

plot(newdf$Participant, newdf$lines_add, type = "l", lwd = 1, col = "blue",
     xlab = "Particpant", ylab = "Ratio of Lines Added", 
     main = "Changes in Code")
```

[image]

If you want to have it as as function to plot all the three lines in a single plot:

```
myplot.participation <- function(data){

  newdf <- aggregate(df[2:4], by= list(df$devf), FUN = "sum")
  newdf <- rbind(c(NA,0,0,0), newdf)
  names(newdf) <- c("Participant", "lines_add", "lines_del", "overall")
  newdf$lines_add <- cumsum(newdf$lines_add)/sum(newdf$lines_add)
  newdf$lines_del <- cumsum(newdf$lines_del)/sum(newdf$lines_del)
  newdf$overall <- cumsum(newdf$overall)/sum(newdf$overall)
  newdf$Participant <- seq(0, length(newdf$Participant)-1)

  plot(newdf$Participant, newdf$lines_add, type = "b", 
       lwd = 2, col = "blue", pch=17,
       xlab = "Particpant", ylab = "Ratio of Changes", 
       main = "Changes in Code")
  lines(newdf$Participant, newdf$lines_del, col="red", type = "b", lwd=2, pch=18)
  lines(newdf$Participant, newdf$overall, col="green", type = "b", lwd=2, pch=19)
  legend("bottomright", 
         legend = c("Lines Added", "Lines Deleted", "Overall"), 
         col = c("blue", 'red', "green"), 
         pch = c(17, 18, 19), 
         text.col = "black", 
         horiz = F)
}

myplot.participation(df)
```

[image]

Ensure that the input data has the columns "Participant", "lines_add", "lines_del", "overall". Else, change the names in the function accordingly.

Comment: nearly, yes i need to have 3 graph one fpr overall one for lines del and one for lines add. I get this with the command line correct?

Comment: Yes, you can compute the overall as a new variable and plot. BTW, is the overall difference between added and deleted?

Comment: no it is the sum off all changes in the projekt referred to the devs

Comment: If you are adding it as anther column, you can use df[2:4] instead of df[2:3] in aggregate function and newdf <- rbind(c(NA,0,0,0), newdf)

Comment: you function is just plottings the graph for lines Addes right?

Comment: Yes you can run lines(newdf$Participant, newdf$lines_del, col="red", lwd=1); 
lines(newdf$Participant, newdf$overall, col="green", lwd=1), if you want to have all the three lines in the same plot.

Comment: is it possible to get the variables without making a new dataframe? With tapply for example? Cause i want to have a plot function which is getting a whole Dataframe as name and then´plots the Three lines.